# unpack function in python

Tags: python, unpack

I am trying to understand the unpack function in Python and how it uses the format string.

I am using the format string, "I" which corresponds to unsigned int (size, 4 bytes) as an example.

As per the documentation, the unpack function will accept a string and convert it to a list of values based on the format string.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html

So, I used the input value as a string, "test" and here is the output:

```
>>> import struct
>>> input="test"
>>> l = struct.unpack("I", input)[0]
>>> print l
1953719668
```

I am trying to understand how the output value was derived from the input.

```
>>> from struct import *
>>> calcsize('I')
4
```

size of 'I' is 4 bytes.
the string, "test" has 4 characters which is 4 bytes.
I tried converting each character to its corresponding Hex ASCII value and storing it in little endian order but it does not match the output above.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `4s` if you want unpack string as is.

```
>>> struct.unpack('4s', 'test')[0]
'test'
```

1953719668 is derived by: (little endian)

```
>>> ord('t') + (ord('e') << 8) + (ord('s') << 16) + (ord('t') << 24)
1953719668
```

Comment: Thanks, I was checking a code which was using "I" as the format string for input string. Could you please elaborate more over how the format string is applied to the input? I thought in little endian it would be like: ord(t), ord(s), ord(e), ord(t). most significant byte to least significant byte. Also, what if the input has a size greater than 4 bytes (size of unsigned int), it will not apply format string to the remaining characters?

Comment: @NeonFlash, ord('t') + (ord('e') << 8) + (ord('s') << 16) + (ord('t') << 24) == (ord('t') << 24) + (ord('s') << 16) + (ord('e') << 8) + ord('t')

Comment: @NeonFlash, size of the format's calcsize() and length of the string should be same. Or, it will raise `struct.error`.

Comment: @NeonFlash, If you want only unpack unsigned long, do something like `struct.unpack('I', input_string[:4])`.